# Javascript Replace the first character

Tags: javascript

How do I replace the first character of a string with another character? I am casting the number as string.

Example: String 12341
New string: 92341

I tried this script but cant figure a way to only replace the first character.

```
var oldStr =12341;
var newStr = oldStr.replace(1, 9);
```

Comment: You can simply slice the first character and append new character`"9" + str.slice(1);`

Comment: Thats a great idea. Thank you!. Let me try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `oldStr` is not a string, it's a number.
2. `replace` has to replace characters, not numbers.
3. So coerce the number to a string, and then do the replacement.

```js
const oldStr = 12341;
const newStr = oldStr.toString().replace('1', '9');
console.log(newStr);
```